False Alert Labels Pine script
I have  one code through which I get label alerts, but there is a problem. I get false alerts where the labels are deleted. I only need the alerts which are true( Alerts shoud not be triggered for deleted labels). In below code I am deleting some labels Eg ( B2.delete()) . These alerts are still coming irrestive of labels which are deleted.
Request you to please help here. I need only alerts for labeles which are white and visible in the chart.
Thanks a lot in advance ,
Mayur
var label H1 = na
var label H2 = na
var label H3 = na
var label B1 = na
var label B2 = na
t1 = time('0930', session.extended)  // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter

//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug
is_first = na(t1[1]) and not na(t1) or t1[1] < t1
day_high = float(na)
day_low = float(na)

if is_first and barstate.isconfirmed
    day_high := high1
    day_low := low1
    day_low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]
    day_low

if high1 > day_high 
    day_high := high1
    day_high
    B1 := label.new(x=bar_index, y=high+30, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, size = size.tiny)
    //line.new(bar_index + 25, high[0], bar_index, high[0], extend = extend.none, color = color.white, width = 3, style=line.style_solid)
    alert("EF",alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if low1 < day_low 
    day_low := low1
    day_low
    B2 := label.new(x=bar_index, y=low-30, text="", color=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, size = size.tiny)
    //line.new(bar_index + 25, low[0], bar_index, low[0], extend = extend.none, color = color.white, width = 3, style=line.style_solid)
    alert("GH",alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)


//plot(day_high, color=color.new(color.black, 0))
//plot(day_low, color=color.new(color.black, 0))

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t2 = time('0930', session.extended)  // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
is_first1 = na(t2[1]) and not na(t2) or t2[1] < t2

DAY_HIGH10 = float(na)
DAY_LOW10 = float(na)

if is_first1 and barstate.isconfirmed
    DAY_HIGH10 := HIGH10
    DAY_LOW10 := LOW10
    DAY_LOW10
else
    DAY_HIGH10 := DAY_HIGH10[1]
    DAY_LOW10 := DAY_LOW10[1]
    DAY_LOW10

if HIGH10 > DAY_HIGH10 
    B1.delete()
    DAY_HIGH10 := HIGH10
    DAY_HIGH10
   

if LOW10 < DAY_LOW10 
    B2.delete()
    DAY_LOW10 := LOW10
    DAY_LOW10
   

I tried different options but the false alerts are still getting generated


you're creating alerts when the B2 label is created and again when it is deleted. Just remove the alert function on whichever one you don't want an alert for.

Hello AmphibianTrading, Yes, I tried this option still I am getting false alert. The reason is first B1 and B2 white label alerts are coming and later some B1 and B2 alerts are getting deleted (Black label overlaping white label, which I dont want) based on the t2 condition.  This means Black label overlaping white label are getting deleted but alerts for them are coming. Can you please help here

you can't delete an alert like you can a label. You need to remove the alert function from the section of code you don't want an alert for
